# Scichart chart did not display xaxis label value

Tags: c#, scichart

I am starting working with scichart and i try to display on XAxis using CategoryDateTimeAxis the date of some result. I want to display only the date for the first result if are more from the same date. My problem is that when i load the first time the results the first date is not displayed. But when i reselect the results the first date appear.

I tried to re-render the chart, but nothing.

This is how the chart looks when i load first time the results
[image]

This is how it looks chart after press day check box or reselect the results.
[image]

The difference is that date under the first result which no appear first time and i don't understand why. Can someone help me with this?

The code for custom label.

```
 /// <summary>
    /// Formats the label.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="dataValue">The data value.</param>
    /// <returns>Returns the format label.</returns>
    public override string FormatLabel(IComparable dataValue)
    {
        var time = (DateTime)dataValue;
        var labelValue = string.Empty;
        if (time.Date == lastValue.Date)
        {
            labelValue = string.Empty;
        }
        else
        {
            switch (Settings.DateFormat)
            {
                case DateFormat.DayMonthYear:
                    {
                        labelValue = time.Day.ToString().PadLeft(2, Convert.ToChar("0")) + "." +
                               time.Month.ToString().PadLeft(2, Convert.ToChar("0")) + "." + time.Year;
                        break;
                    }

                case DateFormat.YearMonthDay:
                    {
                        labelValue = time.Year + "-" + time.Month.ToString().PadLeft(
                                   2, Convert.ToChar("0")) + "-" +
                               time.Day.ToString().PadLeft(2, Convert.ToChar("0"));
                        break;
                    }

                default:
                    {
                        labelValue = time.Month.ToString().PadLeft(
                                   2, Convert.ToChar("0")) + "/" +
                               time.Day.ToString().PadLeft(2, Convert.ToChar("0")) +
                               "/" + time.Year;
                        break;
                    }
            }
        }

        lastValue = time;
        return labelValue;
```

}

Comment: This looks to me like you have some non-standard configuration of axis gridlines, axis label templates and scrollbars which might be the reason for the problems you are seeing. Perhaps try to remove customisations until the problem goes away? If you have a code sample of how to get the problem, share it & update the question here.

Answer (score 0):

In the above question image, it appears that the SciChartSurface has some kind of customisation to the axis labels, possibly via a template.

In SciChart WPF you can customise the Axis Labels and styling as follows:

- [Templating the Axis Panel](https://www.scichart.com/documentation/win/current/Axis%20Styling%20-%20Templating%20the%20Axis%20Panel.html)
- [Templating the Axis Labels](https://www.scichart.com/documentation/win/current/Axis%20Styling%20-%20Templating%20Axis%20Labels.html)

You can also show/hide labels or adjust label positioning with the following properties:

- AxisBase.DrawLabels
- [AxisBase.MajorDelta and MinorDelta](https://www.scichart.com/documentation/win/current/Axis%20Ticks%20-%20MajorDelta,%20MinorDelta%20and%20AutoTicks.html)
- [AxisBase.TickProvider](https://www.scichart.com/documentation/win/current/Axis%20Ticks%20-%20TickProvider%20and%20DeltaCalculator%20API.html)

It's worth checking if you are using any of these APIs that may be causing XAxis labels not to show.